# scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: scala

I am iterating with a map with key-value as

```
Map(fields -> List(
  pangaea_customer_id, email_hash, savings_catcher_balance, 
  is_savings_catcher_member, billing_zipcode
))
```

I am trying below code to get the value of fields key

```scala
val fields = ValuesMap.get("fields")
```

But I am not able to convert fields to comma-separated String.

Please help me on how to do this.

I am trying with

```scala
        val fields = ValuesMap.get("fields").mkString(",")
```

but it will return

```
List(pangaea_customer_id, email_hash, savings_catcher_balance, 
     is_savings_catcher_member, billing_zipcode)
```

Comment: `get` returns an `Option[List[String]]`. If that's intentional then you need to look inside the `Option` to get at the `List`.

Comment: Try: `ValuesMap("fields").mkString(",")`

Comment: try ValuesMap.get("fields").toList.mkString(",")

Comment: Is the title related to the question? When did you get this error?

Answer (score 1):

`get` returns an `Option[V]` (because the key may be unmapped, and then it needs to return `None`).

`Option` can be iterated, just like a `List`, so you can call `mkString` on it, but it only ever returns at most one element, so the separator character will not be used.

Try `getOrElse("fields", Seq.empty).mkString(",")`

What your version did is:

- `get("fields")` returns `Some(List(....))`
- you call `mkString` on the `Option`, will will just give you either an empty String (if it was `None`), or (in your case), the result of `toString` for the element inside (which is the `List` as a whole).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

val fields = res8.get("fields").getOrElse(List()).mkString(",")

// output: **fields: String = pangaea_customer_id,email_hash,savings_catcher_balance,is_savings_catcher_member,billing_zipcode**